# To set an condition for the canvas Height and Width which can't be negative?

Tags: java, oop

Create the following two sub-classes that extend your Artwork class from exercise 1.
Sculpture that has the properties:

- Material
- Weight
  Painting that has the properties:
- Paint Type (e.g. watercolour, acrylic, oil)
- Canvas width
- Canvas height
  Add relevant constructors (using super), getters and setters to your Sculpture and Painting
  classes. Your painting and sculpture classes must extend the base Artwork class. In your
  setters add validation for canvas width, weight and canvas height to prevent an artwork
  existing with a negative value for its size/weight. If an invalid painting is created you should
  show an error.
  Add at least one Sculpture object and one Painting object to your program and make calls to
  superclass and subclass methods.
  I want the program not to accept the negative value for the height and the width. But when I take the input it does not work i.e. it accepts the negative value

  ```
    class Artwork2 {
    String Artist;
    int Value;

    public Artwork2(String artist, int value) {
        this.Artist=artist;
        this.Value=value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.Value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.Value=value;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return this.Artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.Artist=artist;
    }
    }

    class Sculpture extends Artwork2 {
    protected String material;
    protected double weight;
    public Sculpture(String artist, int value, String material, double weight) {
        super(artist, value);
        this.material=material;
        this.weight=weight;
    }

    public String getMaterial() {
        return this.material;
    }
    public void setMaterial(String material) {
        this.material=material;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight=weight;
    }

    }


    class Painting extends Artwork2 {
    protected String paintType;
    protected double canvasWidth;
    protected double canvasHeight;
    public Painting(String artist, int value,String paintType, double canvasWidth, double canvasHeight) {
        super(artist, value);
       this.paintType=paintType;
       this.canvasHeight=canvasWidth;
       this.canvasWidth=canvasHeight;
    }

    public double getCanvasWidth() {
    return this.canvasWidth;
    }
        public void setCanvasWidth(double canvasWidth) {
        this.canvasWidth=canvasWidth;
    }

    public double getCanvasHeight() {
        return this.canvasHeight;
    }
    public void setCanvasHeight(double canvasHeight) {
        if (canvasHeight < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();}
            this.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
    }

    public String getPaintType() {
        return this.paintType;
    }

    public void setPaintType(String paintType) {
         this.paintType=paintType;
    }
     }

      public class SuperClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sculpture sculpture= new Sculpture("lap", 1000,"top", 99);
  ```

System.out.println(sculpture.getArtist()+sculpture.getMaterial()+sculpture.getValue()+sculpture.getWeight());

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    double canvas=in.nextDouble();
    Painting painting =new Painting("lap", -1000,"oil", canvas, -10);
            System.out.println(painting.getArtist()+  
   painting.getCanvasHeight()+painting.getCanvasWidth()+painting.getPaintType()+
    painting.getValue());
}
```

}

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. We could help with specific bugs, but you haven't provided the information needed. Please provide the full text of the error or exception, and the stack trace if possible. Paste these, as text, into your question.

Comment: I have done the most part and was finding an error while taking the negative value. I had an bug at that point so I have asked. I did not ask for the homework-writing service though I was seeking for the help to solve the bug.

Comment: And yet, even after your comment, you still haven't posted the error or exception. Please don't handicap the volunteers who are trying to help you.